# How to trigger validation before submission in parsley?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I'm now using parsley 2 to validate my form, it works fine except this problem: only after you submit your form for the first time, the validation will be triggered when you change your input, but before submission, it will do nothing.

That said, I want to trigger validation before the first submission. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need to use `data-parsley-trigger="keyup"`(http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-form) if you want that your fields auto-validates on keyup event.

You could define it field by field, or on the whole form is directly in the `<form>` tag.

Best